# /data/user/0/com.m4coding.ide/files/support/dbclient: Connection to test@localhost:3088 exited: Connect failed: Connection refused

Tags: xml, error-handling, aide, android-wifi-debugging

So I keep getting a stupid error on aide for no reason, it says /data/user/0/com.m4coding.ide/files/support/dbclient: Connection to test@localhost:3088 exited: Connect failed: Connection refused. But there is no code that says to connect to 3088 or localhost

I tried to search for localhost:3088, and the ability to delete it. Nope!

---

Ps: >! DONT criticize me, as I'm a new xmler.

<sup>so</sup> <sub>uhhh</sub>thanks!